# How would I test for a Application with a certain title being the active window and return the value?

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file

I'm not super experienced in coding. I'll admit I know that the bare basic of the concept should be possible considering I've seen these particular strings while searching for this very thing on other sources:

```
if (title === "") {
sh.SendKeys(keys);
WScript.Quit(0);
}
if (sh.AppActivate(title)){
sh.SendKeys(keys);
WScript.Quit(0);
} else {
```

However, I'm not sure how to set up a JavaScript excerpt or how to test to see if a specific title is the active window and return the value back to the batch-file if true or false how would I do so? I'm currently using this:

```
:loop
@echo off
tasklist /V /FI "IMAGENAME eq Test.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Test.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Working
goto loop
```

However, it's not able to detect the active window or anything like that so I began searching for JavaScript and figured out that it should be possible. However, the code I found was for sending keys and not particularly what I needed.

Of course, I don't intend to take credit for others work but I'm just trying to piece something semi-functional together. I want to have a program run only while another program is active and close when it isn't the active window.

Comment: You clicked "ask a question", but you haven't asked a question? Surely if you run a batch file, the active window will be a command prompt running your batch file, that's going to skupper any simple approach.

Comment: Is _How to get the active window title?_ your actual question?

Comment: I'm wanting to know how to test for a certain active window title and return a positive/negative result to a batch file

Comment: @LilBlaez, then see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I misunderstand you, but if your actual question is how to retrieve the `active window title` from batch, you must use an `hybrid` script containing both batch code and another language code that can call the windows api.

There are lot of examples about `hybrid batch scripts`, here is `c#` which does the proper API calls.

```
//>nul 2>nul||@goto :batch_code
/*
:batch_code
@echo off
setlocal
set "theExeFile=getForeWinData.exe"
if not exist "%theExeFile%" call :build_the_exe || exit/B

for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=^^" %%a in ('%theExeFile%') do (
  echo/Foreground window title is [%%a]
  echo/Created by process [%%b] thread [%%c]
  echo/
  echo/Now do whatever you wanna do with this info
)
endlocal
exit /b 0

:build_the_exe
:: find csc.exe
set "frm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /a:d  /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*"') do (
   set netver=%%v
   goto :break_loop
)
:break_loop
set "csc=%frm%%netver%\csc.exe"
:: csc not found
if "%csc%" == "\csc.exe" echo/&echo/Warning: Net Framework Not Found&exit/B 1
::csc found
call %csc% /nologo /out:"%theExeFile%" "%~dpsfnx0" 
exit/B 0
*/

//begin c# code
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class GetWindow {
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();  
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);  
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);  
  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)] static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint processId);

  public static void Main()
  {
    string strTitle = string.Empty;  
    IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();  
    int intLength = GetWindowTextLength(handle) + 1;  
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(intLength);
    uint procId=0;
    uint thrdId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, out procId);
    if (GetWindowText(handle, stringBuilder, intLength) > 0)  
      strTitle = stringBuilder.ToString();
    strTitle = string.Format("{0}^{1}^{2}", strTitle, procId.ToString(), thrdId.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(strTitle);
  }
}
```

Save this as i.e `test.bat` and run it. The first time, it will create the `getForeWinData.exe` as it doesn't exist, and then call it in a `for` loop to grab its output. Once the exe is created, you may remove the `hybrid` part and simply call the newly created `exe`.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "theExeFile=getForeWinData.exe"

for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=^^" %%a in ('%theExeFile%') do (
  echo/Foreground window title is [%%a] 
  echo/Created by process [%%b] thread [%%c]
  echo/
  echo/Now do whatever you wanna do with this info
)

endlocal
exit /b 0
```

Another example of `hybrid` batch, now using `cscript` to minimize the *calculator* if it is open.

```
@echo off

set "lookFor=Calculator"

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ('tasklist /nh /fo csv /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq %lookfor%"') do set "pid=%%~A"

>"%TEMP%\close.vbs" (
  echo/Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
  echo/oShell.AppActivate %pid%
  echo/WScript.Sleep 500
  echo/oShell.SendKeys "%% (n)" ' minimize (Alt+SpaceBar,n^)
)

start /B cmd /C "CScript //nologo //E:vbs "%TEMP%\close.vbs" & del /F /Q "%TEMP%\close.vbs" >NUL 2>NUL"

exit/B
```

EDIT: to check for a certain window title

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "theExeFile=getForeWinData.exe"

for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=^^" %%a in ('%theExeFile%') do (
  if /i "%%a" == "my window title text" (
    echo let's do some action here
  )
)

endlocal
exit /b 0
```